# Regular expression to replace a particular text contains Leading,Trailing Spaces or Special Char

Tags: java, regex

How to replace the String  with `****` If the string surrounded with Leading or Trailing Spaces or special char.

Below are the example of possible patterns:

1. `" Sonia "` as `****`
2. `" Sonia"` as `****`
3. `"Sonia "` as `****`
4. `"Sonia,"` as `****,`
5. `"{Sonia}"` as `{****}`

Note : The String is a dynamic string constructed from java

Which pattern I need to use to replace the string ?

Comment: What string exactly do you want to replace?

Comment: You mean you only want to replace the string if it's surrounded by spaces? Use the `\b` word boundary pattern around it.

Comment: @Barmar that will also replace if it has punctuation around it.

Comment: why not add "****" instead of name() in the first place?

Comment: Please show examples covering all edge cases.  If you only want to mask certain types of words, then give us the full logic here.

Comment: Please provide valid test cases.

Comment: Last `S` has comma after so why is that getting replaced?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I suspect that's what he really wants.

Comment: What makes a brace a special character, but not a comma?

Comment: May be I'm completly wrong but why not simply search for `\w+`  and replace with `****`?

Comment: `redActemailBody.replaceAll("(?<!\\w)"+requesterView.getFirstname()+"(?!\\w)","****");` I am using this and it is working as expected Thanks @Toto

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace words surrounded by spaces then you can use this lookaround based regex replacement in Java:

```
String input = "Dear Cdr. Sonia S S,";

String repl = input.replaceAll("(?<= )\\p{L}+(?= )", "****");
//=> Dear Cdr. **** **** S,
```

- `(?<= )` - Lookbehind to assert that previous character is a space
- `(?= )` - Lookahead to assert that next character is a space

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZdpZS/9)